# Display syntax highlighter on root/main page in Jekyll pages

Tags: jekyll, syntax-highlighting, liquid, pipeline, truncate

Well, I'm trying to figure out how could I display highlighted syntax.

But actually I have two main issues. The principal one is that if I show the `post.content` using the template pipes:

For example: `{{ post.content | markdownify }}`

The following content is shown:

[image: ...]

[image: ...]

As you can see, the blocks of the main page is shown with a white background. While the posts are shown with dark background. I'm comparing the two templates to see if I'm missing something, but I don't see the thing I'm missing (I think is a CSS (missing include) problem).

**Note:** I already tried to include js.html from the theme. But I doesn't do so much.

Also, the other problem is that if I use more pipes to cut the content (because I don't want to see all the content), using: `strip_html | truncatewords: site.post-preview-words` in the `{{ post.content | markdownify }}` pipe. The following occurs:

- Using only `truncatewords` the main page styles are broken.
- Using also `strip_html` the contents are shown as plain content.

I know why this is happening. Is there any gem/plugin to truncate the content taking care of unclosed html tags? Is there any approach using the default pipes of Jekyll?

This is the theme I'm actually using: https://github.com/le4ker/personal-jekyll-theme

This is my main Github.io page: https://z3nth10n.github.io